# Cannot create an instance of an abstract class

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new in android kotlin and try to write this code in java:

```
SliderView sliderView = new SliderView(this);
```

to kotlin code :

```
val sliderView =SliderView(this)
```

but get this error:

> Cannot create an instance of an abstract class

how can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: can you post SliderView code

Comment: @sasikumar thanks my friend to pay attention to my problem,why post all of the SliderView code?in first line of that code get error

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53822654/10127727

Comment: Have you tried using this? `val sliderView = object: SliderView` ?

Comment: `SliderView` seems like an abstract class that has unimplemented functions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create objects of the abstract classes. 
Read more: https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/abstract-class

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class can’t be instantiated. Read more about it:
https://www.journaldev.com/1582/abstract-class-in-java

Answer (score 0):

The error implies the `SliderView` class is abstract. You can't do that in Java either, so if your Java code compiled the name `SliderView` now refers to a different class; check the imports or Ctrl-click on the name in your IDE to see if you go to the class you want.